# How is the voltage and current plot for a matched transmission line constant?

Tags: transmission-line

When the transmission line is terminated with a matched load the voltage on the line is given by V(z)=E e^(jβz).
where β is the phase constant of the line.

1)How is the voltage plot a constant for this transmission line?

2)How is e^(jβz) represented on the line?[image: The voltage and current on the matched transmission line can be seen in Fig 7-6 (c)]

The voltage and current on the matched transmission line can be seen in the above figure, Fig 7-6 (c)

Comment: There are no standing waves on a correctly terminated t-line.

Comment: I'm sorry. It was the voltage and current plot of the matched transmission line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there is an impedance change in (or at the end of) a transmission line, energy is reflected from the point of the change, resulting in a flow of energy in both directions from that point.

These two flows are summed at every point along the line, sometimes adding to each other, and sometimes partially or wholly cancelling out. The relative phase between the two flows is determined by the distance from the discontinuity.

When there is no discontinuity, there is no reflected energy, so the voltage and current levels measured at every point along the line are the same.

Comment: But doesn't the graph disobey the equation V(z)=E e^(jβz). According to the equation we should expect a sinusoidal voltage along the length of the line

Comment: It is sinusoidal, but the graph is just showing the magnitudes of the current and voltage, not including their signs.

Comment: "not including their signs." --- I'd rather say it's not including their *phases*.